# Can 12/2 cable be exposed in a crawl space?

Tags: wiring

I have installed 9 "QuiteWarm Radiant Heat Film for under subfloor" to heat the floor above a crawl space off the the basement.  The crawl space has a concrete slab and is tempered.  This subfloor system is a 120v. system, with a total load  of 900 watts, 7.5 amps for the 9 panels. Each radiant heat film panel comes with a separate  black and white 12 ga. wire.  The instructions say to run all the wires (black and white)to a junction box, wire them in parallel and run a 12/2 Romex to the Thermostat.  The Thermostat gets power from a separate 15 amp breaker circuit.  The thermostat has a built in GFI.  My question concerns the single 12 ga. wires from the film panels to the junction box.  Can the single 12 gauge wires be run exposed in the crawl space(fastened per code along joist or 2x6) or do they need to be put in conduit or something else?.
Thanks

Comment: Where do you live? At minimum I would suggest to use UFB wire since a crawl space is technically a wet location and is exposed to the elements/wildlife. If you have a rodent problem and fear it will get chewed then use conduit.

Comment: By "single wires" do you actually mean the cable (what you call "Romex")?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, you can't make that assumption about crawl spaces. Many I've worked in are every bit a basement including floor slab, albeit with shorter walls.

Comment: As I understand you, each panel has 2, shortish, individual #12 wires that you then connect to the "house wiring". Are you asking about these short, individual wires, or are you asking about the "house wiring" (that I understand you're adding new)? Pics of what you've got would be quite helpful.

Comment: @isherwood You're right. I'm just surprised that OP didn't see any other wires in their basement to tip them off before posting this question. Had they said "vertically challenged section of basement" then I would have more readily made the correct association :-)

Comment: @GenePost, can you verify whether your crawl space is a wet or dry location?

Comment: It is a dry location with insulated concrete walls and concrete floor with access directly from the basement.  The crawl  is about 4ft in height and has been dry for 25 years and I have not seen any signs of pests.   I would say it is no different that a basement only shorter( height).  The location is in Wisconsin.  The 12 ga. wire are single insulated wires that are part of the heating element panel and are each about 20' long.  It is not romex.  It is similar to one of the insulated wires in 12/2 romex cable but with out the outer sheating.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of one of these heat panels and the wires which they supply? I am surprised that the device does not have a built-in junction box for you to tie in the NM-B wire. I recall that individual wires cannot be run at any length so you'd have to provide your own sheathing, conduit, or armor. I also recall that the NMB jacket must enter the junction box which rules out the supplied cables' ability to be routed to a junction box in the first place.

Comment: However https://youtu.be/NtsTeItVUd4?t=226 shows that they are running individual wires to a junction box.

Comment: @ monkeyzeus, that link shows a horrible code violation the notch with no nail plate.  But as the install is protected by GFCI as required by code it’s not a big deal. You haven’t done any heated floors have you? I have done many both under floating floors and tile. A crawl space is not a normally wet location! Look at the code reference you can see code allows NMB in basements and crawl spaces. 334.15.C and exhibit 334.1

Answer (score 2):

Yes a crawl space can have your 12/2 attached directly to the floor joists if going along the joist if going perpendicular a rat run is needed for smaller than 2 ea #6 or 3 ea #8 wires see exhibit 334.1 in the code , nmb in this location has been code for decades. Rat run or 1/2” plywood minimum.
Note bored holes need no protection.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't address OP's concern about the individual cables which come from the panels per "My question concerns the single 12 ga. wires from the film panels to the junction box."

Comment: what is a 'rat run'? Never heard this expression before

Comment: A rat run is a board or plywood nailed to the bottom of the joists when going perpendicular to the joist (or exposed below the joist) sorry it’s an electrician slang term. Placed on top of ceiling joist is the other location the term rat run is used.  @ monkeyzeuse as only the op referred to “12-2 cable” and Romex are at the boxes my answer directly answers the question with the code reference. Of wiring in a crawl space as required by code you can say it doesn't answer it but the cable coming from the breaker to the junction boxes go according to my answer and code reference let the OP decide